# Searching if value exists in a list of objects using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Say I have a class `Customer` which has a property `FirstName`. Then I have a `List<Customer>`.

Can LINQ be used to find if the list has a customer with `Firstname = 'John'` in a single statement.. how?

Answer (score 572, accepted):

LINQ defines an extension method that is perfect for solving this exact problem:

```
using System.Linq;
...
    bool has = list.Any(cus => cus.FirstName == "John");
```

make sure you reference System.Core.dll, that's where LINQ lives.

Comment: Any is good, I wonder how many developers use Count when they should use Any?

Comment: You can also do a case insensitive search:
cus => cus.FirstName.Equals("John",
           StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)

Comment: I know this is an old question but why aren't we making use of the Exists method? Seeing as it is made to see if things exist.

Comment: Because not all collections have Exists, and it does not take a lambda expression, but rather the object we are looking for itself.

Comment: @zvolkov, Any ideas why my resharper is suggesting I use bool has = list.All(cus => cus.FirstName != "John");  Is this more optimal ?

Answer (score 125):

zvolkov's answer is the perfect one to find out *if* there is such a customer. If you need to *use* the customer afterwards, you can do:

```
Customer customer = list.FirstOrDefault(cus => cus.FirstName == "John");
if (customer != null)
{
    // Use customer
}
```

I know this isn't what you were asking, but I thought I'd pre-empt a follow-on question :) (Of course, this only finds the *first* such customer... to find all of them, just use a normal `where` clause.)

Comment: I'd point out that you might appreciate having done this later when it comes to debugging, if you find yourself suddenly curious which customer it was that fit the criteria.

Comment: Just bumping this answer up one cos I love the way SO community goes the extra step to add even more to the question/answer.

Comment: thanks it helped me, but sometimes i just want to get `bool` result , so in that case `.Any` or `.FindIndex` is used [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4937099/2218697) **which is fast**  ?

Comment: @stom: They're both O(N), basically... they're just linear searches.

Answer (score 29):

One option for the follow on question (how to find a customer who might have any number of first names):

```
List<string> names = new List<string>{ "John", "Max", "Pete" };
bool has = customers.Any(cus => names.Contains(cus.FirstName));
```

or to retrieve the customer from csv of similar list

```
string input = "John,Max,Pete";
List<string> names = input.Split(',').ToList();
customer = customers.FirstOrDefault(cus => names.Contains(cus.FirstName));
```

Answer (score 10):

Using Linq you have many possibilities, here one without using lambdas:

```
//assuming list is a List<Customer> or something queryable...
var hasJohn = (from customer in list
         where customer.FirstName == "John"
         select customer).Any();
```

Answer (score 7):

```
customerList.Any(x=>x.Firstname == "John")
```

Comment: This does not answer the question "if" such an entry exists; it merely enumerates the values if they do exist. An extra step is needed to determine if this enumeration is nonempty.

Comment: Then change the Where to Any.  Probably more philosophical for me.  I rarely need to know if without caring which ones they are.

@jmservera: you were right.  I gave up LINQ a while back and now use Lambda exclusively.

Comment: I don't mean to be pedantic when I say that using the lambda calls is still technically using LINQ. (In particular, you're using LINQ-to-Objects.) You're just using the method calls rather than language keywords.

Comment: How does this answer differ from the zvolkov's?

Answer (score 4):

The technique i used before discovering `.Any()`:

```
var hasJohn = (from customer in list
      where customer.FirstName == "John"
      select customer).FirstOrDefault() != null;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
List<Customer> list = ...;
Customer john = list.SingleOrDefault(customer => customer.Firstname == "John");
```

john will be null if no customer exists with a first name of "John".

Comment: That will throw an exception if *more than one* customer is called John.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'll leave the answer as a partially correct example.

Comment: It's still valid in a scenario when you are sure there is 1 and you want an exception to be raised if more than one, so I think it is good that you didn't delete it.

Answer (score 3):

Try this, I hope it helps you.

```
 if (lstCustumers.Any(cus => cus.Firstname == "John"))
 {
     //TODO CODE
 }
```

Comment: That's the same as the accepted answer from over 8 years ago. Please make sure your answer is unique among all the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility

```
if (list.Count(customer => customer.Firstname == "John") > 0) {
 //bla
}
```

Comment: Its' preferable to use Any in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Include using System.Linq

Use Trim() if there should be a match even with leading and trailing
whitespaces.

Use StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase if the match needs to
be case insensitive.

```
using System.Linq;
...
    bool has = list.Any(cus => cus.FirstName.Trim().Equals("John", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
```