# Best way to check if object exists in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, exists

What is the best way to check if an object exists in the database from a performance point of view? I'm using Entity Framework 1.0 (ASP.NET 3.5 SP1).

Answer (score 260, accepted):

If you don't want to execute SQL directly, the best way is to use [Any()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.any.aspx). This is because Any() will return as soon as it finds a match. Another option is [Count()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb918829.aspx), but this might need to check every row before returning.

Here's an example of how to use it:

```
if (context.MyEntity.Any(o => o.Id == idToMatch))
{
    // Match!
}
```

And in vb.net

```
If context.MyEntity.Any(function(o) o.Id = idToMatch) Then
    ' Match!
End If
```

Comment: And in VB If (context.MyEntity.Any(o => o.Id <> idToMAtch)) Then ' This is a match! End If
Sorry, this isn't in the code tag, I couldn't figure out how to do it!

Comment: Think you mean o.Id <> idToMatch is NOT equal to a match

Comment: what if I search by name and I want to get the ID if it exists?

Comment: hi. how can we check if it exists and after that select all its data?

Comment: @virtouso Do the .Any() check then execute the query. I don't think there is an API call to do this, but you could write your own helper method.

Comment: what if you want to **use the MyEntity afterwards** instead of writing a second query to database ? check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1071063/2218697), hope helps someone.

Comment: I am trying to write `protected bool IsExists(int id){ return T.Any(c => c.Id.Equals(id)); }` but `c.Id` is giving me error as it is a generic class. Another way I thought of would be `protected bool IsExists(int id){ return T.Find(id) != null ; }`. But I want to use the former one. How can it be done?

Comment: `Any` still seems to fetch all values from the db. using `Find() != null` would be lighter

Comment: @barnes If you constrain `T` to an interface that is `IEnumerable` and return objects that contain an `Id`, you should be able to use your generic function `IsExists<T>()`.

Answer (score 9):

From a performance point of view, I guess that a direct SQL query using the [EXISTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms188336.aspx) command would be appropriate. See here for how to execute SQL directly in Entity Framework: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2009/11/25/execute-t-sql-statements-in-entity-framework-4.aspx

Comment: Yeah, good idea but im limited to a previous version of entity framework.

Answer (score 5):

I had to manage a scenario where the percentage of duplicates being provided in the new data records was very high, and so many thousands of database calls were being made to check for duplicates (so the CPU sent a lot of time at 100%).  In the end I decided to keep the last 100,000 records cached in memory.  This way I could check for duplicates against the cached records which was extremely fast when compared to a LINQ query against the SQL database, and then write any genuinely new records to the database (as well as add them to the data cache, which I also sorted and trimmed to keep its length manageable).

Note that the raw data was a CSV file that contained many individual records that had to be parsed.  The records in each consecutive file (which came at a rate of about 1 every 5 minutes) overlapped considerably, hence the high percentage of duplicates.

In short, if you have timestamped raw data coming in, pretty much in order, then using a memory cache might help with the record duplication check.

Comment: Many a time we developers come up with your scenario, may be with some twists. I would like to request you to translate your solution in C# so that we and many upcoming developers would benefit. +1. I would love the solution expanded up to a blog post either! :)

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a very old thread but just incase someone like myself needs this solution but in VB.NET here's what I used base on the answers above.

```vb
Private Function ValidateUniquePayroll(PropertyToCheck As String) As Boolean
    // Return true if Username is Unique
    Dim rtnValue = False
    Dim context = New CPMModel.CPMEntities
    If (context.Employees.Any()) Then ' Check if there are "any" records in the Employee table
        Dim employee = From c In context.Employees Select c.PayrollNumber ' Select just the PayrollNumber column to work with
        For Each item As Object In employee ' Loop through each employee in the Employees entity
            If (item = PropertyToCheck) Then ' Check if PayrollNumber in current row matches PropertyToCheck
                // Found a match, throw exception and return False
                rtnValue = False
                Exit For
            Else
                // No matches, return True (Unique)
                rtnValue = True
            End If
        Next
    Else
        // The is currently no employees in the person entity so return True (Unqiue)
        rtnValue = True
    End If
    Return rtnValue
End Function
```

Comment: I don't know how to use Lambda in VB but in C# this is equivalent: return !context.Employees.Any(c => c.PayrollNumber == PropertyToCheck). This avoids returning all the results then looping through in memory.

Comment: @Colin this is a good addtion I overlooked the memory issue with the above code, in VB the code is context.Employees.Any(c => c.PayrollNumber <> PropertyToCheck). I've now added this to my code.

Comment: Kevin, I think you may have to go back and fix your code. Your logic is surely returning true if there are any payroll numbers that don't match, rather than true when there are not any matching payroll numbers.

Comment: @Colin sorry you are right, I was providing a VB version to your example only I don't right much C# and thought == was not equal to hence my VB <>.

Comment: @KevinMorrissey I think coling was saying you need to put a "Not" in front of "context." since "return Not context.Employees.Any(c => c.PayrollNumber = PropertyToCheck)" IS NOT (I repeat), _IS_ _NOT_ the same as "return context.Employees.Any(c <> c.PayrollNumber = PropertyToCheck)".

Do you see my point? Using "return Any <>" means if you find any that doesn't match this number (even if a matching one exists), will return true no matter what. Instead, using "Not [...].Any =" will only return True when it can't find the row you're looking for! Do you see the difference?

Comment: @Colin Sorry, both the msgs were meant for Kevin and Colin.

Answer (score 2):

I had some trouble with this - my EntityKey consists of three properties (PK with 3 columns) and I didn't want to check each of the columns because that would be ugly.
I thought about a solution that works all time with all entities.

Another reason for this is I don't like to catch UpdateExceptions every time.

A little bit of Reflection is needed to get the values of the key properties.

The code is implemented as an extension to simplify the usage as:

```
context.EntityExists<MyEntityType>(item);
```

Have a look:

```
public static bool EntityExists<T>(this ObjectContext context, T entity)
        where T : EntityObject
    {
        object value;
        var entityKeyValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>();
        var objectSet = context.CreateObjectSet<T>().EntitySet;
        foreach (var member in objectSet.ElementType.KeyMembers)
        {
            var info = entity.GetType().GetProperty(member.Name);
            var tempValue = info.GetValue(entity, null);
            var pair = new KeyValuePair<string, object>(member.Name, tempValue);
            entityKeyValues.Add(pair);
        }
        var key = new EntityKey(objectSet.EntityContainer.Name + "." + objectSet.Name, entityKeyValues);
        if (context.TryGetObjectByKey(key, out value))
        {
            return value != null;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: I'd like to add a comment to my answer that is now almost 9 years old. I think nowadays there are much cleaner solutions and possibilities than there were in 2010/2011 with Entity Framwork 4. So I would recommend to stop down-voting this answer but instead add a new/better answer below.

Comment: Please also keep in mind that my solution was a generic one that worked for many entities with composite keys of existing tables/entites I could not change. So instead of always querying .Any(...) with 3 key properties I simply called .EntityExists().

Answer (score 2):

I just check if object is null , it works 100% for me

```
    try
    {
        var ID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Params["ID"]);
        var Cert = (from cert in db.TblCompCertUploads where cert.CertID == ID select cert).FirstOrDefault();
        if (Cert != null)
        {
            db.TblCompCertUploads.DeleteObject(Cert);
            db.SaveChanges();
            ViewBag.Msg = "Deleted Successfully";
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Msg = "Not Found !!";
        }                           
    }
    catch
    {
        ViewBag.Msg = "Something Went wrong";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it?

```
var result= ctx.table.Where(x => x.UserName == "Value").FirstOrDefault();

if(result?.field == value)
{
  // Match!
}
```

Comment: This will throw a null reference exception because FirstOrDefault() will return null if it can't find a result. 
I guess you could do if(result?.field == value) to avoid that.

Comment: This can be unnecessarily slow since it loads the entity. If all you want to do is check that a key exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

### Best way to do it

Regardless of what your object is and for what table in the database the only thing you need to have is the primary key in the object.

### C# Code

```
var dbValue = EntityObject.Entry(obj).GetDatabaseValues();
if (dbValue == null)
{
   Don't exist
}
```

### VB.NET Code

```
Dim dbValue = EntityObject.Entry(obj).GetDatabaseValues()
If dbValue Is Nothing Then
   Don't exist
End If
```

Comment: Why two almost identical answers? The difference is insignificant. Also, this certainly isn't the best way to do it. It doesn't make sense to pull al values form the database only to check if a record *exists*.