# Entity framework and Exists clause

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework

I'm a rookies of EF so, sorry for my perhaps foolish question.

I've 2 entities without any relationship (VS does not load the join and I can't manually add it because the primary key of the child uses a derivated key of its parent).

Example

Entity master
Products
keys GKey_K, Product_K
fields .....

Entity detail
GenericInformation
keys GKey_K, GI_K
fields Product_K, ....

Well, my question is simple (I hope also my english!), how I can read only the products that have some reference on GenericInformation?

TIA

> **Possible duplicate:**
>    [Best way to check if object exists in Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802286/best-way-to-check-if-object-exists-in-entity-framework)

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of 1802286 as this is retrieving the Products, whereas in that question it's just checking for existence of a single object.

Answer (score 33):

`EXISTS` in SQL ~= `Any` in LINQ:

```
var q = from p in Context.Products
        where Context.GenericInformation.Any(gi => gi.Product_K == p.Product_K)
        // add other columns to the where if need be; I can't tell what the 
        // relationship is supposed to be
        select p;
```