# Entity framework exists clause with lambda

Tags: entity-framework, lambda

I've seen an answer to a similar problem ([Entity framework and Exists clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379183/entity-framework-and-exists-clause)), but not using lambda and I would like to understand what is wrong, 
whether it is my mapping or if is the way to use. I'm using Entity Framework 5.

Here is my mapping:

```
public class Attribute : EntityWithGuid
{
    ... Other mappings ....

    [InverseProperty("Attribute")]
    public virtual ICollection<CategoryAttribute> CategoryAttributes { get; set; }
}

public class Category : EntityWithGuid
{
    ... Other mappings ....

    [InverseProperty("Category")]
    public virtual ICollection<CategoryAttribute> CategoryAttributes { get; set; }
}

public class CategoryAttribute : EntityWithGuid
{
    ... Other mappings ....

    [ForeignKey("Category_Id")]
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public string Category_Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Attribute_Id")]
    public virtual Attribute Attribute { get; set; }
    public string Attribute_Id { get; set; }
}
```

If I run the command below, it works fine and the result SQL is

```
var query = Attribute.Where(x => !x.CategoryAttributes.Any());

SELECT 
    Extent1.Id,
    Extent1.Name,
    Extent1.Type,
    Extent1.Active
FROM
    Attribute AS Extent1
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS( SELECT 
            1 AS C1
        FROM
            CategoryAttribute AS Extent2
        WHERE
            Extent1.Id = Extent2.Attribute_Id)
```

But if I put one more clause appears a Project2 alias for Attribute instead Extent1 and gives error because inside the exists clause within the remains Extent1.Id

```
var query = Attribute.Where(x => !x.CategoryAttributes.Any(y=>y.Category_Id == idcategory));

SELECT 
    Project2.Id,
    Project2.Name,
    Project2.Type,
    Project2.Active
FROM
    Attribute AS Project2
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS( SELECT 
            1 AS C1
        FROM
            CategoryAttribute AS Extent2
        WHERE
            (Extent1.Id = Extent2.Attribute_Id)
                AND (Extent2.Category_Id = @p__linq__0))
```

The exception is

> Unknown column 'Extent1.Id' in 'where clause'

Comment: Can you post the exception?

Comment: The expection is {"Unknown column 'Extent1.Id' in 'where clause'"}

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.

After performing a simple query and receive an error similar thought something was wrong. Below the query, SQL and the undesirable alias Project

```
User.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(partialName))

SELECT 
    Project1.Id,
    Project1.Name
FROM
    User AS Project1
WHERE
    (LOCATE('Marcelo', Extent1.Name)) > 0
ORDER BY Project1.Name ASC
```

Recently I upgraded MySql and with it came the new Net connector, version 6.7.4. I went back to the previous Net connector version (6.5.6) and everything is working again.