# Select WHERE IN in entity framework

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I want to write an entity query for this SQL command:

```
SELECT * FROM provider WHERE serial 
         NOT IN ( SELECT providerRef as Serial FROM ProviderTeam WHERE TeamRef=134)
```

I searched the internet but no answer.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342817/entity-framework-attribute-in-clause-usage. Also you can rewrite the query using EXISTS and see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379183/entity-framework-and-exists-clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite your IN clause as EXISTS and use the following linq command:

```
var q = from p in dbContext.Providers
        where !dbContext.ProviderTeams.Any(pt => pt.TeamRef == 134 && pt.providerRef == p.serial)
        select p;
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope this is what you need:

```
using (var dbObj = new [DB_NAME]Entities())
{
    var list = dbObj.provider.SqlQuery("SELECT * from provider where serila NOT IN ( select providerRef as Serial from ProviderTeam where TeamRef=134)").ToList();
}
```