# Generic Way to Check If Entity Exists In Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, generics, entity-framework-4.1

Similar to [Best way to check if object exists in Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802286/best-way-to-check-if-object-exists-in-entity-framework)

I'm looking for a generic way to check for an entity in a `DbSet`. Something like this, which doesn't work:

```
private DbContext DbContext { get; set; }

private DbSet<T> DbSet { get; set; }

public Boolean Exists(T entity) {
    return ((from item in this.DbSet
             where item == entity
             select item).Count() > 0);
}
```

The line `where item == entity` works in LINQ to SQL, but apparently not with LINQ to Entities. Since the entities may have different keys I can't have them all inherit from a common abstract with a known key for comparison.

<strike>I could do this, but I'm worried about the performance of catching exceptions as a verification process</strike> This doesn't work either since as long as the entity is detached the `OriginalValues` property can't be obtained:

```
public Boolean Exists(T entity) {
    try {
        var current = this.DbContext.Entry(entity).OriginalValues;
        // Won't reach this line if the entity isn't in the database yet
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: To clarify the reason for wanting a generic `Exists()` method, I want to be able to create a `Save()` method where it can be determined whether the entity needs to be added to the context (`INSERT`) or attached (`UPDATE`). I didn't mention this in the question as once I have `Exists()`, `Save()` becomes trivial.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Do you want generic way to check if entity was loaded by context or generic way to query database if entity exists?

For the former case use:

```
public bool Exists<T>(T entity) where T: class
{
    return this.Set<T>().Local.Any(e => e == entity);
}
```

For the latter case use (it will check loaded entities as well):

```
public bool Exists<T>(params object[] keys)
{
    return this.Set<T>().Find(keys) != null;
}
```

**Edit:**

EF code first is not supposed to access this kind of information but it is possible to get name of entity keys. I think something  like that should work:

```
var objContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext;
var objSet = objContext.CreateObjectSet<T>();
var keyNames = objSet.EntitySet.ElementType.KeyMembers.Select(m => m.Name);
```

But this all doesn't make sense. You want generic approach but your entities doesn't share necessary information to allow generic approach. Now you say that you even don't know key values. Using this "generic" approach will require reflection and manual building of expression tree.

Comment: Using `context.Set<T>().Local.SingleOrDefault(e => e == entity);` works, but of course requires that I read the entire set into memory - something that realistically I can't do in most situations. And `context.Set<T>().Find(keys);` works, but as I mentioned, I won't always know the keys for the entity passed in. Unless there's a way to ask EF which properties are being used as keys?

Comment: Some answers not only answer the question, but also point you to a new door you didn't know it exists. `Local` property, I knew about, right now, thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't it be like - `public bool Exists<T>(T entity) where T: class` ? Or not class but some other datatype given, just wondering.

Comment: Won't `this.Set<T>().Find(keys)` load the entire entity? This can have serious performance implications if this is in a tight loop. Especially if all you need to check is if the key exists.

Comment: There might be an issue if you are using an InMemory DbContext, where setting a non-existing entity as modified could cause it to be added to internal memory before it throws an error. So, if you do an existence check within a catch, that entity could show up as existing if you first try to set it as modified.

Answer (score 20):

Thanks to @Ladislav for getting me in the right direction. Here's the code for a generic `Exists()` method.

I'd like to note that this doesn't require reflection and seems to perform quite well. The only thing I'm not thrilled about is that `TryGetObjectByKey()` has the side-effect of attaching the found entity. Since I don't want `Exists()` to have that unintentional result I have to detach the entity if it was found.

```
public Boolean Exists(T entity) {
    var objContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this.DbContext).ObjectContext;
    var objSet = objContext.CreateObjectSet<T>();
    var entityKey = objContext.CreateEntityKey(objSet.EntitySet.Name, entity);

    Object foundEntity;
    var exists = objContext.TryGetObjectByKey(entityKey, out foundEntity);
    // TryGetObjectByKey attaches a found entity
    // Detach it here to prevent side-effects
    if (exists) {
        objContext.Detach(foundEntity);
    }

    return (exists);
}
```

Comment: But `Attach` and `SaveChanges` won't save any changes because attaching leaves the entity in state `Unchanged`. You must set the state to `Modified` after `Attach`. But this is ineffective since all columns will be updated no matter if they really did change. To avoid this you have to load the original into the context and apply the changes on property level. But then you don't need `Exists` since it would only cause to load the entity twice. And what will you do when `entity` has navigation properties and related objects have to be updated or not? I have doubt in a generic `Save` approach.

Comment: @Yuck: I'm only talking about the "if"-case, not the "else"-case of course. I don't see how this could save anything, it even won't issue any SQL command to the database. Quote from here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/29/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-4-add-attach-and-entity-states.aspx **...Note that no changes will be made to the database if SaveChanges is called without doing any other manipulation of the attached entity. This is because the entity is in the Unchanged state...** And I can confirm this from my own tests.

Comment: @Yuck: No, that's wrong. It doesn't update. If you have a `User` in the database with `Id` = 1 and `Name` = "Paul" and then *attach* a `User` entity with `Id` = 1 and `Name` = "Mary" to the context and then directly call `SaveChanges`, the `User` with `Id` = 1 in the database still has the name "Paul". (I'm talking about EF 4.1 too, but it doesn't matter, this behaviour is EF core stuff.)

Comment: As it turns out I have some nasty side-effecting that's allow the object to be saved the way this is written. I'm going to edit out my `Save()` since it wasn't relevant to the original question anyway. I'll be starting a new question to track progress and hopefully get additional comments on. Thanks for your help @Slauma.