# Entity Framework: Update entity or add if it doesn't exist

Tags: sql, optimization, entity-framework-4, sql-update

I have a scenario where I have to update an entity if it exists or add a new one if it doesn't.

I would like to execute a single method for this (it would be great if it were a single trip to the server).

Is there something like that in EF?

Right now my code looks like this:

```
var entity = db.Entities.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == myId);
if (entity == null)
{
    entity = db.Entities.CreateObject();
    entity.Id = myId;
}

entity.Value = "my modified value";

db.SaveChanges();
```

But I would like to avoid the first query, something like this:

```
var entity = new Entity();
entity.Id = myId;
entity.Value = "my modified value";
db.AddOrAttach(entity);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Is there anything similar? or do I have to perform the first query no matter what?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at my question about doing generic save with EF: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018711/generic-way-to-check-if-entity-exists-in-entity-framework the result of which was to write a generic save method (insert or update as required). It quickly gets messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to perform the first query no matter what, unfortunately.

One option would be to write a stored procedure that performs a T-SQL `MERGE` then map it to a function import, though that would require that you pass the scalar values of the entity as parameters (and support for navigation properties would be done), but it would accomplish what you're after.

Comment: That would be too much work for each table where I have this issue. Maybe I'll do it if this becomes a performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

I ran some quick test code for **editing** in MVC 3 with EF 4 and it seems to work for edit with following code:

```
using (var context = new TestStackOverFlowEntities())
{
    Person p = new Person();
    p.Id = long.Parse(collection["Id"]);
    p.FirstName = collection["FirstName"];
    p.LastName = collection["LastName"];
    context.People.Attach(p);
    context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(p, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
    context.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Edit: I checked with creating new object too, you need to change this

```
context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(p, System.Data.EntityState.Added);
```

when Id == 0 //ie new object.

Quick and dirty code to add new is this:

```
using (var context = new TestStackOverFlowEntities())
{
    Person p = new Person();                        
    p.Id = 0;
    p.FirstName = collection["FirstName"];
    p.LastName = collection["LastName"];
    context.People.Attach(p);
    context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(p, System.Data.EntityState.Added);
    context.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: You're not focusing on the main question. Your response assumes that I know if I want to update or insert. The whole idea of the question is that I don't know what should happen.

Comment: "I have a scenario where I have to update an entity if it exists or add a new one if it doesn't." -- The sample I gave you handles that, but the assumption I made is the entityId would be 0 for newly added and > 0 for existing ones. That won't work for something like a GUID.

Comment: Yep, but in my case the element I'm adding has a foreign key as a composed primary key therefore it won't ever be zero. If I had the zero I could just use that instead of the first query of my code.

Comment: BTW: I tested something else again, I have 
 System.Data.EntityState.Added
for both scenarios (ie edit and adding) and it seems to be working fine. Give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to limit code to clarify your controllers:

```
db.Attach(model);
db.SaveChanges(model);
```

Will update if the Entity Key exists, and create if it does not.