# How to properly mark entity already attached to context as modified?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository

I feel like there should be an easy answer to this, but I can't quite seem to wrap my mind around it.  I have a repository that was initially generated by the [MvcScaffolding tool](http://nuget.org/packages/MVCScaffolding/), so it has a method that looks like this:

```
    public void InsertOrUpdate(PhysicianSchedule physicianSchedule)
    {
        if (physicianSchedule.Id == default(int)) {
            // New entity
            context.PhysicianSchedules.Add(physicianSchedule);
        } else {
            // Existing entity
            context.Entry(physicianSchedule).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }
```

This initially worked well to note when a physician schedule entity was brand new or existed but needed to be updated.  I have a unique index set up for three specific fields in this entity, since I can't have two different schedules on file with the same values for those fields (specifically, the physician ID, department ID, and the effective date).

In my MVC controller, I added some model validation to make sure that someone wasn't adding a new schedule or editing an existing one that would have values in those three fields that match a different entry on file:

```
    private void ValidateMatchOnFile(PhysicianScheduleViewModel physicianScheduleViewModel)
    {
        PhysicianSchedule matchingScheduleOnFile = physicianScheduleRepository.Find(physicianScheduleViewModel.PhysicianId,
                                                                   physicianScheduleViewModel.DepartmentId,
                                                                   physicianScheduleViewModel.EffectiveDate);

        if ((matchingScheduleOnFile != null) && (matchingScheduleOnFile.Id != physicianScheduleViewModel.Id))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("EffectiveDate", "There is already an effective date on file for this physician and department.");
        }
    }
```

The above two methods are basically called in sequence when making an edit to a schedule, so they share the same Entity Framework DbContext object (via the repository).  **This, however, is ultimately causing my problem:** assuming there is no matching schedule on file other than the existing one being edited, the ValidateMatchOnFile() method attaches the current physician schedule entity to the EF context **prior** to the InsertOrUpdate() method attaching it (via the line invoking **context.Entry()**).  I then get the expected InvalidOperationException error:

**"An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key."**

What I don't know is the best way to work around this.  Should I change how I look for a matching (but different) entity on file in the ValidateMatchOnFile() method?  Should I look to see if the entity to be inserted in InsertOrUpdate() already exists in the local context?  In regards to the latter approach, I followed the lead of [Ladislav's answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6019273/603661) and inserted this into my InsertOrUpdate() method:

```
// Check to see if entity was already loaded into the context:
bool entityAlreadyInContext = context.Set<PhysicianSchedule>().Local
                                     .Any(ps => ps.Id == physicianSchedule.Id);
```

and it works fine to determine if the entity does in fact exist in the local context, but I'm not sure how to rewrite the **else** portion of the IF statement to reflect whether the entity has already been attached to the context or not.

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4 and EF5.  Thank you for any help!

---

**Update with my solution**, thanks to Gert:

Instead of trying to use the method in DbContext called Any() during the InsertOrUpdate() call, I instead created a new method in my repository that checked for the existence of what I was looking for, without actually attaching the matching entity into my context.  I added this method to my repository (the name is admittedly not very elegant):

```
    public bool MatchingScheduleDifferentId(int physicianScheduleId, int physicianId, int departmentId, DateTime effectiveDate)
    {
        bool test =  context.PhysicianSchedules.Any(ps => ps.Id != physicianScheduleId && ps.PhysicianId == physicianId && ps.DepartmentId == departmentId && ps.EffectiveDate == effectiveDate);
        return test;
    }
```

And then I simplified the logic in the validation method in my MVC controller to this:

```
    public void ValidateMatchOnFile(PhysicianScheduleViewModel physicianScheduleViewModel)
    {
        bool matchingScheduleOnFile = physicianScheduleRepository.MatchingScheduleDifferentId(physicianScheduleViewModel.Id,
                                                                                              physicianScheduleViewModel.PhysicianId,
                                                                                              physicianScheduleViewModel.DepartmentId,
                                                                                              physicianScheduleViewModel.EffectiveDate);

        if (matchingScheduleOnFile == true )
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("EffectiveDate", "There is already an effective date on file for this physician and department.");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a method to your repository: `Any`, so you can do

```
physicianScheduleRepository.Any( ... your parameters ...);
```

Inside, the method executes

```
return context.PhysicianSchedules.Any(s => s.Id == physicianId 
                                        && s. .... the other crietria);
```

This does not fetch any entity into the context and only sends a boolean (bit) over the line.

Comment: Interesting - I didn't even think of using Any() in relation to the Validation I do prior to calling the InsertOrUpdate() method.  Instead of naming your proposed new method in my repository "Any", I went with Exists(), which I see some other people have done, based on other similar questions here.  And it worked great - thanks Gert!  I'll update my question with my working solution.