# Entity Framework 6 - .Create new object, save changes, re-query object based on new id, null return

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I recently upgraded our solution from EF4.1 to EF6.  Our previous create method added the detached object to the context, saved changes, then requeried the object based on the new id.  We requery the object because we do not use lazy loading, and use includes/selects to get navigational properties - which are added by taking the IDbSet and returning an IQueryable.  In short, I cannot just return the existing in-memory copy - because it would not be fully loaded up.  I have tried detaching the in-memory copy.  I cannot flush the dbcontext (because I am working with other objects in the same context).

Anyway, the big issue, my big issue is that in the EF6 branch when I requery that object it returns a null record - not finding the one I just created.  The record is persisted to the database - I can see it.  If I create a new dbcontext and query for that record I can find it.

```
dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Add(model);

dbContext.SaveChanges();

var newCopy = dbContext.Set<TEntity>().SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == model.Id);
```

In this instance, newCopy is always null.  But if I get a new dbContext - I can get the object fine.

Anyway, I need to solve this issue.  Any ideas?

Comment: Might not be related, but I got problems with queries when I upgraded my EF 4.1 project to EF 6.1. Solution was targeting the 4.5.1-Framework in the project. Did *not* work with only 4.5.

Comment: Hi Stephan - everything else seems to be working fine.  We are using .NET 4.0.  It is just really this requery issue - and a few issues with deeply nested includes.

Comment: Please could you post the code?

Comment: Hi buffjape - I did just above.  I just omitted the dbcontext and getting of the set.

dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Add(Model);

dbContext.SaveChanges();

dbContext.Set<TEntity>().SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id = Model.Id);

side note: I have tried a where also - nothing queries the object short of a new dbContext.

Comment: What happens if you query with actual type rather than generic argument?

Comment: does `_context.Set<TEntity>().Find(id)` return anything? (where `id` is an object)

Comment: Also, you are not using a second-level cache on the dbContext, are you? And have you double-checked to make sure that model.Id is not zero after SaveChanges?

Comment: Hi Stilgar - I will try it out - in essence it is typed - but I will throw a hard reference in and see.

Brett Caswell - I will try it - I won't be able to use Find because I need to be able to use Includes (Find is only good when using lazy loading I have read - might be wrong).

I don't know danludwig - I do not believe so.  Whatever is default for 6.1.

Comment: danludwig - the model id is > 0 - it is saving and returning the id just fine.

Comment: @DanHirsch it is probably stored in the `Local` collection, i.e. the dbcontext won't find it in the database as a "new" object.. I'll try to find some references and add something based on that, but until then, you should find it in the `dbContext.Set<>().Local` collection.

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018711/generic-way-to-check-if-entity-exists-in-entity-framework) is a question with an answer that might benefit you..

Answer (score 1):

I actually discovered what the issue was/is.  In EF4, it really doesn't matter if the mappings are HasRequired or HasOptional.  However, if you use a HasRequired on a nullable integer field (legacy db) - then it actually is performing an inner join and will not select the record - resulting in a return of null.  Since I am not using lazy loading - but rather eager loading - if I have an include on the above described mapped field - it returns a null.

Thanks everyone for their help - it was appreciated!

Comment: Hmmm... the code in the OP did not have any `.Include` extensions... so did the code in the OP actually return `null` or not?

Comment: Hey dan - to simplify the code I put the Set<> in directly...  I had forgoten that my GetSet method (which returns the Set) actuall makes another call out to includes.  It was the multiplicity of the mappings that got me.  Thanks for your help though - it all pointed me toward a solution... When I did try it as stated above, I got a result.

Answer (score 0):

Does the following work:

```
dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Add(model);

dbContext.SaveChanges();

var newCopy = dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Find(model.Id);
```

I won't claim to know the ins an outs of it but I am using that in the same situation and it works.

You could also check that the model properties are not virtual as EF6 takes this as lazy loading (You may have already done this).