# Look up locally cached entity by key in EF 6 / Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

EF 6, Code First

I am looking to write a `TryGetLocalEntity()` method for EF 6 `DbContext` that will lookup an entity by key and return it if it exists in `DbContext.Set<TEntity().Local`. I want to do the lookup based on entity key and not object reference.

So the method signature might be:

```
    public static bool TryGetLocalEntity<TContext, TEntity>(this TContext context, TEntity entity, out TEntity cachedEntity)
        where TContext : DbContext
        where TEntity : class
    {

        EntityKey key = ???GetEntityKey???(entity);
        cachedEntity = context.Set<TEntity>().Local.Where(e => ???).FirstOrDefault();
        return cachedEntity != null;
    }
```

The purpose for this is to take an entity that has been deserialized from another source and either 1) `Attach()` it to the `DbContext` if it doesn't exist locally (determined by entity key and not object reference) or 2) retrieve the locally cached entity if it does exist (again determined by entity key and not object reference).  I know I can just get it from the DB, but I'd like to avoid the round-trip if I already have what I need.

The main step I think I am missing is creating an `EntityKey` from a detached POCO entity.  From here, I think I can figure out how to look up in the `DbContext` based on `EntityKey`.

**UPDATE** Here's a crack at it.  Obviously some hacks, and I haven't tested it yet:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Core;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Pluralization;

    public static bool TryGetLocalEntity<TContext, TEntity>(this TContext context, TEntity entity, out TEntity cachedEntity)
        where TContext : DbContext
        where TEntity : class
    {
        EnglishPluralizationService pluralizationService = new EnglishPluralizationService();
        string setName = pluralizationService.Pluralize(typeof(TEntity).Name);
        ObjectContext objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
        EntityKey key = objectContext.CreateEntityKey(setName, entity);
        try
        {
            cachedEntity = objectContext.GetObjectByKey(key) as TEntity;
        }
        catch (ObjectNotFoundException)
        {
            cachedEntity = null;
        }
        return cachedEntity != null;
    }
```

**UPDATE**  What I have seems to work *except* when an entity exists in the context but hasn't been saved to the database yet.  I've been digging around in the EF source trying to determine if an unsaved/added entity doesn't have an `EntityKey`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
var objContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
var objSet = objContext.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>();
var entityKey = objContext.CreateEntityKey(objSet.EntitySet.Name, entity);
```

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.core.objects.objectcontext.createentitykey%28v=vs.113%29.aspx
- [Generic Way to Check If Entity Exists In Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018711/generic-way-to-check-if-entity-exists-in-entity-framework)

Comment: hey, hey, looks like it was 4 min ago, I was probably in the middle of typing it :/

Comment: I keep editing as I refine it so people don't waste their time.  Maybe not the best approach haha