# How to get values from the specific column names

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
string[] data = { "Col1", "Col2", "Col3" };

tblMain main = _serviceRepository.GetMainData(record.ExtractID);

foreach (string colName in data)
{

}
```

I have a string which consists of column names of a table. And I'm getting a data from database using entity framework. The data will be only one row which I'm saving as a tblMain type. Now I want to compare the array with the column names in the table.

If that column name exists in the table then I need to get the data from the table. Is there a way to do this?

tblMain is a sort of model

```
public partial class tblMain
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Col1 { get; set; }
    public string Col2 { get; set; }
    public string Col3 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What are the characteristics of your `tblMain` class? If it's similar to the `DataTable` class, then there should a collection of columns so that you could compare just the names or check if it exists as a name. But we cannot help further since we have no info about your custom class.

Comment: Here tblMain is nothing but a model. We can not get the column names here. Or I think I don't know how to get it here. I have edited my question , have a look at it once again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generic Way to Check If Entity Exists In Entity Framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018711/generic-way-to-check-if-entity-exists-in-entity-framework)

Comment: Why are you using strings for the column names in the first place?  Can you not just query the columns in a type-safe manner and avoid reflection or other methods?

Comment: Yes, tell some more about what you're trying to achieve in a wider sense. I sense that there is a much easier way to get there.

Answer (score 0):

You could use reflection to do that with the class PropertyInfo.
If you want to get the data from a column, have to pass in parameters the result of a query which is an object 'tblMain' from Entity Framework to the method GetValue

This is an example how you could get data of Col1:

```
tblMain queryResult = ctx.tblMain.first(); // get your fist row in the DbSet

PropertyInfo prop = tblMain.GetType().GetProperties(data[0]);
string col1Value = prop.GetValue(queryResult);
```

Of course, you could add validation with the method PropertyExist()