# Can EF6 automatically check an object against the primary key of the mapped DB type?

Tags: entity-framework, generics, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I have a generic method which is called when an external source sends me an object, to persist to the DB which I want to work like this...

```
public void PersistToDB<T>(T object)
{
 using(var dbContext = ...)
 {
  //if(dbContext.Set<T>.Any(x => x.PrimaryKeyMatches(object))...
 }
}
```

I do not keep these objects in memory, just save them - either INSERT or UPDATE. My issue is that while I can do `dbContext.Set<T>.Any(x => x.id == object.id)` or `dbContext.Set<T>.Find(object.id)` to find if an object exists, I have to know the fields on which to search. EF surely knows which fields define the PK for `T` so I was hoping I could pass it `object` and it would do this for me automatically, or provide me a delegate I can pass into `Any`, but I cannot see how?

Calling `dbContext.Entry(object)` does *not*, as I understand it, do what I want... it will instead tell me the specified object is in `Detached` state as no local copy is held.

Is there a way I can do what I want without having to write type-specific code which spoils my neat generic implementation?

**EDIT:** based on the stuff in [Generic Way to Check If Entity Exists In Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018711/generic-way-to-check-if-entity-exists-in-entity-framework/6019273#6019273) I think much of this is covered. What I'm really after is a way to create a Delegate/ACtion `func` around that code which I can then pass to `Any(x => func(x))`

Comment: I don't think there is any way you can do this without using reflection or having a base class/interface that defines the primary key for all your entities.

Comment: It just seems like since I tell EF what the primary key is (I use Fluent API rather than data annotations) it should know... doesn't it HAVE to know for certain operations in fact?

Comment: I think it does know, but doesn't expect you to ask! Perhaps this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/6019273/1663001

Comment: You can pass a Func which specifies the column(s) to find

Comment: @ErikEJ you're correct but then I still have to write type-specific code - unless you can think of a neat example you'd like to share?

Comment: @DavidG that definitely looks promising. I'm not sure if it's an exact answer yet!

Comment: I will try to dig something out!

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, this is what I've ended up doing. Though I can generate a PK automatically based on type, I can't see a way to dynamically generate a lambda expression around that. So I had to go the `Find` route rather than the `Any` route which does have the slight issue of pulling each object from the DB. However, this does mean that only the columns which have actually changed get updated on existing objects which I suppose at least partly mitigates that.

```
        using(var dbContext = ...)
        {
            var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext;
            var objectSet = objectContext.CreateObjectSet<T>();
            string entitySetName = objectSet.EntitySet.Name;

            //find the PK columns and values for this type and instance
            var entityKey = objectContext.CreateEntityKey(entitySetName, item);
            var pk = entityKey.EntityKeyValues.Select(_ => _.Value).ToArray();

            var entity = dbContext.Set<T>().Find(pk);
```

I don't know how efficient the first part is but you could obviously cache this to some extent.