# How can I prevent logical duplicates with EF Code first?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

Given a simple class like Person, with a FirstName, LastName and DOB property as well as an Id property (which is the primary key).

When I make a call to my create action I want to perform a validation to determine if the model I am passing in, with FirstName, LastName and DOB properties happens to match any records that already exist. In this case I want to exclude the Id property because the model coming into the app does not have one yet and would create false positives.

Currently I am just using the Any extension method like so...

```
if (!context.People.Any(x => x.FirstName == model.FirstName && x.LastName == 
model.LastName && x.DOB == model.DOB))
```

Which certainly works but is entirely, well, not elegant.

Surely there is a better way?

Comment: You might be able to avoid stuff like this with unique constraints on your DB, and then proper error handling in your code. If you want to check for duplicates before values are persisted, then I think `Any()`, while not exactly elegant, is perfectly OK.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to check if object exists in Entity Framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802286/best-way-to-check-if-object-exists-in-entity-framework)

Comment: This is not a duplicate, the answer for the question you referenced is something I said I explicitly want to avoid

Answer (score 1):

If uniqueness is a business requirement, then you should handle this in the database with unique constraints.  Then, you don't need to check, the database will throw an exception and tell you when it's violated.  You handle the exception and tell the user they are already in the system.

Comment: I disagree with this approach. I think it is better to use a validator. You can have a unique constraint in addition to the validation, but you should not expect an exception like this to occur. Just my opinion, though.

Comment: I also disagree, that is a very volatile solution - control flow of the application through exceptions is really high on my list of attributes of bad code.

Comment: @keithwarren7 - this is not control flow.  You're not using the exception to decide to update a record or insert a record.  That would be bad.  This is a case where a user is inserting a duplicate record.  Your only other choice is to query the database first, but you said you didn't want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem you don't want to see the Any call directly in the controller or you just don't like the call at all?

If it is the former, then use a validation framework to hide the details from the controller. If it is the latter then you could create some sort of stored procedure/function in your database and call that instead.

I don't really think that this code is bad, though. I just think it needs to be a validation. FluentValidation is pretty nice for this, but DataAnnotations will work as well.

Comment: I guess the real problem is that, the call to Any depends on writing out each non-key property in the case of each entity, rather than having one generic call. I am thinking right now I might write an extension method that accepts a model and matches values of non-key properties.

So bottom line, I could have asked the question as - 'How can I be more lazy than this...'

Comment: Writing that extension method is exactly what I was working on to answer your question. It seems like the best solution. How can you be more lazy? Ask it on SO and see if someone else will write it for you of course ;)

Comment: @keithwarren7 - An extension method would be a bad idea, because extension methods are static.  You don't want to be querying the database in your extension method because it would keep an open connection for the lifetime of the program.