# Entity framework: writing a common method to check exist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext, system.reflection

My domain class:

```
public class Address
{
    [Key]
    public virtual string AddressId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Address { get; set; }
}
```

In my MVC controller I want to check the given Address exist, before I insert.

```
public ActionResult Create(Address address)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      if (db.Addresses.Any(a => a.AddressId == address.AddressId)) // how I do it now
      {
         ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Address Id already exists!");
      }
      else
      {
         db.Addresses.Add(address);
         db.SaveChanges();
         return RedirectToAction("Index");
      }
   }
}
```

But there are lot of other domain classes in my project and I want to do the same check again and again.

My question is I want to write a generic method **in my Db context** class to perform this check. (looks like below or similar)

```
public bool Exists(object) {
    // return true if exist
}
```

i.e. a method which I can call like this:

```
db.Exists(address)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You could use generics and do something like the following:

```
public class YourDbContext : DbContext
{
    ...

    public bool Exists<TEntity>(object id)
        where TEntity : class
    {
        var dbSet = Set<TEntity>();
        var entity = dbSet.Find(id);
        return entity != null;
    }
```

Which you'd then use like:

```
db.Exists<Address>(address.AddressId);
```

Using `Find` isn't the *most* efficient way to handle this, *but* it has the key benefit that you're not required to know what the actual primary key property on the class is, which would greatly complicate this method. For example, `Address` has `AddressId`, but `Foo` might have `FooId`.

**UPDATE**

Since ultimately this just uses `Find` under the hood, you just have to modify the method slightly to be able to take multiple parameters. `Find` handles composite keys by allowing one more parameters to be passed to it. But bear in mind, the the order matters and must align with the key order you specified when configuring your entity.

```
public bool Exists<TEntity>(params object[] keys)
    where TEntity : class
{
    var dbSet = Set<TEntity>();
    var entity = dbSet.Find(keys);
    return entity != null;
}
```

Comment: Im getting an error at this point `Set<TEntity>`
`'System.Data.Entity.DbContext.Set<TEntity>()' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context`.

My DbContext looks like this:
`public class MyDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>`

Comment: Sorry about that. Moving too quickly and forgot a step.

Comment: Thanks @Chris, it works! var dbSet = Set<`Entity`>(); should be var dbSet = Set<`TEntity`>();

Comment: What if my entity has more than one key? At the end of this [PAGE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802286/best-way-to-check-if-object-exists-in-entity-framework) (the last answer) there is a solution. But I couldn't convert the code to use it with `DbContext`.