# Check if DB already have a DateTime equals to the one passed in the form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, datetime

I'm making in ASP.NET MVC C# like a Web Scheduler. So, I have my Create ActionResult inside my Controller as follows:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,NomeResponsavelEvento,NomeEvento,DataInicioEvento,HorarioInicioEvento,DataFinalEvento,HorarioFinalEvento")] Evento evento)
{
    var teste = from x in db.Eventos where x.HorarioInicioEvento.Hour.Equals(evento.HorarioInicioEvento.Hour) select x;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Eventos.Add(evento);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    else
    {
        TempData["ErroHorarioExistente"] = "Já possui um evento no horário informado! Tente outro horário.";
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(evento);
}
```

What I want to do is check (with a if statement maybe) if in DB already have an event in the same hour:minute of the new create form event. I used some breakpoints in "var teste" but It always show null even if already have in DB an event with the same DateTime of my form. When I tried to do another example as follows in this question: [How to check if a record already exists in the db using asp.Net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34695020/how-to-check-if-a-record-already-exists-in-the-db-using-asp-net-mvc)

I can get it to work as: db.Eventos.Any(ag => ag.DataInicioEvento == evento.DataInicioEvento) but this method check only if some date is equal, and then it return true that already have one same date and it works. But I need it to work for the hour:minute

Comment: I'm assuming the property on your model is a `DateTime`, why can't you do `DateTime.Compare`?

Comment: I tried to reproduce this with windows application, it works as expected. What happens if you put a break point and see what command text is generated and run directly on SqlServer?

Comment: so you have debugged and the dates/times that are being stored in those variables and they are only storing the date portion? I am assuming it would store as something like this: `06/29/2016 00:00:00` if your conditional statement isn't passing..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you should put brakepoint after `var teste = ...`, becuse breakpoint stops before line is execute. Next if you want same hour and minute you can do:

```
var teste = db.Eventos.Where(ag => 
    ag.DataInicioEvento.Hour == evento.DataInicioEvento.Hour 
    && ag.DataInicioEvento.Minute == evento.DataInicioEvento.Minute 
)
```

Comment: Just perfect! Thank you so much for the tip about the breakpoint and for the code. It's working now.