# how to check if List<T> element contains an item with a Particular Property Value

Tags: c#, list, contains

```
public class PricePublicModel
{
    public PricePublicModel() { }

    public int PriceGroupID { get; set; }
    public double Size { get; set; }
    public double Size2 { get; set; }
    public int[] PrintType { get; set; }
    public double[] Price { get; set; }
}

List<PricePublicModel> pricePublicList = new List<PricePublicModel>();
```

How to check if element of `pricePublicList` contains certain value. To be more precise, I want to check if there exists `pricePublicModel.Size == 200`? Also, if this element exists, how to know which one it is?

EDIT If Dictionary is more suitable for this then I could use Dictionary, but I would need to know how :)

Answer (score 217, accepted):

If you have a list and you want to know where within the list an element exists that matches a given criteria, you can use the `FindIndex` instance method. Such as

```
int index = list.FindIndex(f => f.Bar == 17);
```

Where `f => f.Bar == 17` is a predicate with the matching criteria.

In your case you might write

```
int index = pricePublicList.FindIndex(item => item.Size == 200);
if (index >= 0) 
{
    // element exists, do what you need
}
```

Comment: what if i don't know the attribute of that value? e.g. i have a list item that is displaying "18.00" i don't know where it is coming from so i want to check wich attribute has this value? so basically , and similirally to this example i don't have the .size or .bar i want to figure it out

Comment: what if the item doesn't exist: what will the index value be?

Comment: **NOTE:** If the element doesn't exist, `findIndex` will return `–1`. Documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/x1xzf2ca(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @tomloprod that's why he checks for an index greater than or equal to zero. if (index >= 0). Could have also written it as if (index > -1).

Answer (score 166):

```
bool contains = pricePublicList.Any(p => p.Size == 200);
```

Comment: This is strictly to see if one exists.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. He said, `how to know which one is it`

Comment: Might not answer his question, but it sure did help me, because I needed to see if an object with a given name already exists in my collection. I expected an improved .Contains-method - and this is exactly what this LINQ-expression does. Thank you.

Comment: It answers the Question in the *title*. OP explains in his *description* that he doesn't really want exactly what he said he wants. Still, there's one of him, and dozens of us finding this question through google. I think it's more important that we be able to find the real answer to his title question.

Comment: If anyone tries this and **.Any()** is unrecognised, you need to add *using System.Linq;* at the top of your file.

Comment: `.Any` or `.FindIndex` **which is fast**  ?

Comment: This one helps me too.  For my case I don't care which one it is, just whether it exists or not.

Answer (score 50):

You can using the exists

```
if (pricePublicList.Exists(x => x.Size == 200))
{
   //code
}
```

Answer (score 17):

This is pretty easy to do using LINQ:

```
var match = pricePublicList.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Size == 200);
if (match == null)
{
    // Element doesn't exist
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to directly edit the element that matches this condition? Not to get it and store in new object, but change directly?

Comment: The `match` value that is returned can be modified (it is the `PricePublicModel` object that was in the list).

Comment: You should not directly modify an object that can be null. You can always do: `match.Size = 300;` or `foreach(var item in pricePublicList.Where(p => p.Size == 200)) item.Size = 300;`. Would not use it as a one-liner myself, though.

Answer (score 14):

You don't actually need LINQ for this because `List<T>` provides a method that does exactly what you want: [`Find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc.aspx).

> Searches for an element that matches the conditions defined by the specified predicate, and returns the first occurrence within the entire `List<T>`.

Example code:

```
PricePublicModel result = pricePublicList.Find(x => x.Size == 200);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
var item = pricePublicList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Size == 200);
if (item != null) {
   // There exists one with size 200 and is stored in item now
}
else {
  // There is no PricePublicModel with size 200
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just use `List.Find()`:

`if(pricePublicList.Find(item => item.Size == 200) != null)
{
    // Item exists, do something
}
else
{
    // Item does not exist, do something else
}`