# C# Searching List of custom objects for specific string within object

Tags: c#, list, constructor, contains

I am trying to search a list of objects for a specific "trait" of said object

Below are the classes that create the objects for the lists:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Dice_Roller_v3._14
{
    public class ImageBase
    {
        public Bitmap Image { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    public class ColorBase
    {
        public Color Color { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the code that creates lists of objects from the constructors.

```
    public partial class frmImage_Layer : Form
    {
        //Create lists for storing colors and images
        public List<ColorBase> ImgColor = new List<ColorBase>();
        //public List<String> ImgPath = new List<string>();
        public List<ImageBase> ImgBase = new List<ImageBase>();
        public frmImage_Layer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

This code contains an example of how the list is being assigned to

```
        private void btnImageControl_Control_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ErrorHandling("control") == true)
            {
                return;
            }
            if (radImageControl_Color_Add.Checked == true)
            {
                cpImageControl.ShowDialog();
                ImgColor.Add(new ColorBase(){Name = txtImageControl_Name.Text,Color = cpImageControl.Color});
                ArraysChanged();
            }
            else if (radImageControl_Color_Delete.Checked == true)
            {

            }
            else if (radImageControl_Part_Add.Checked == true)
            {

            }
            else if (radImageControl_Part_Delete.Checked == true)
            {

            }
        }
        public void ArraysChanged()
        {
            //This is not related to the original question, but if someone knows how to fill a 
            //Combo-box with the list it would save me quite some time
            cmbImageControl_Color.Items
        }
```

Below is where i am trying to search for the text, as simply typing ImgColor.Contains("text") won't work in this context, i have emptied the if statements in question.

```
        public bool ErrorHandling(string Type)
        {
            if (Type == "control")
            {
                if (txtImageControl_Name.Text == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Name must not be blank", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    return true;
                }
                else if ()
                    //Want to check if ImgBase contains a name equal to the text in txtImageControl_Name.Text
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Name cannot be identical to a name already in place", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    return true;
                }
                else if ()
                    // Want to check if ImgColor contains a name equal to the text in txtImageControl_Name.Text
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Name cannot be identical to a name already in place", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

The non-relevant code has been redacted for readability.

Comment: Or this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937060/how-to-check-if-listt-element-contains-an-item-with-a-particular-property-valu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for

```
if (ImgBase.Any(x => x.Name == txtImageControl_Name.Text))
   ...
else if (ImgColor.Any(x => x.Name == txtImageControl_Name.Text))
   ...
```

Comment: That works perfectly, Thank you, would you mind explaining how it works?

Comment: @KawaiiDouchebag its just enumerating a collection and returning true or false on the expression in the lambda, in this case, is the name of any element in the collection equal to the text of the control

Comment: I see that x is being used as a wild card of some form during x.name, but what is the x => part used for?

Comment: "*enumerating*" is referring to iterating over each item in a collection, not "*enumeration type*"

Comment: yes, apologies, i had noticed that too late and edited my comment to the relevant parts

Comment: `=>` is a lambda expression. Its a function. x refers to the current item being iterated. the function is on the right returning true or false for the Any Method

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt and helpful responses, have a good day!