# Simple LINQ to Entities translation

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6, extension-methods

**Before anyone jumps on a mark as duplicate, I have looked and everyone is doing something slightly more complicated than I am trying.**

So I'm working on a database where there's a lot of data to check and LINQ's Any() extension translated to SQL isn't as fast as SQL's Count(1) > 0, so everywhere I'm writing:

```cs
var someBool = Ctx.SomeEntities.Count(x => x.RelatedEntity.Count(y => y.SomeProperty == SomeValue) > 0) > 0;
```

> In Pseudo: Does any of my entities have a relationship with some other entity that has a property with a value of SomeValue.

This works fine and it works fast. However, it's not exactly readable (and I have lots of them, more embedded than that in cases) so what I'd like to do is replace it with:

```cs
var someBool = Ctx.SomeEntities.AnyX(x => x.RelatedEntity.AnyX(y => y.SomeProperty == SomeValue));
```

with:

```cs
public static bool AnyX<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate) => source.Count(predicate) > 0;
```

So you see I'm not doing anything that LINQ can't translate to SQL, I'm not doing anything that LINQ doesn't already translate to SQL, but just by creating an additional extension I get:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method Boolean AnyX etc...

There must be some way of writing my extension or some way of telling LINQ just to take a look at the code and you'll see you can do it.

Comment: Why are you using AnyX instead of just Any?

Comment: I see 2 big problems, first EF deals with `Expressions`, not delegates; pass an `Expression<Func<TSource, bool>>` instead of a `Func<TSource, bool>`, and it needs to extend `IQueryable<>`, not `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Yeah I tried all that, still didn't work. What you see there is a copy of the Any() extension definition.

Comment: @jdweng As I said in the question Any() isn't as fast as Count() > 1 and yes it makes a difference. I can't use Any for my own extension as it'll cause ambiguity.

Comment: @Tod You copied the code for the IEnumerable version of `Any`.  The IQueryable version is different. [IEnumerable](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,6a1af7c3d17845e3) Version, [IQueryable](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/IQueryable.cs,0d55b633eacb158e) version

Comment: It is critically important that you understand the difference between extending  `IEnumerable` and `IQueryable` when trying to "enhance" entity framework in this way.  If you are operating on an `IEnumerable`, it will run on the local computer, it will NOT be translated in to SQL.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/36736907/1625737

Comment: If it was so simple, everyone won't be *"doing something slightly more complicated than I am trying."*. LINQ to Entities query translation is based on a set of known methods and is not extendable (at least not in a simple way - you can find a lot of 3rd party libraries trying to address it with custom queryable implementations and expression tree transforming visitors). LINQ is not C# compiler, it can't "see" your custom method implementation.

Comment: Look into [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit).

Comment: Note that `COUNT() > 0` and `EXISTS` (LINQ translation for `Any`) should be the same in MS SQL 2005 or greater - perhaps you should ask why the SQL for `Any` is slow?

Comment: PS Your `someBool` statement has an extra `)` and should be slower than `Any`.

Comment: @NetMage Checkout this previous conversation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648795/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-determine-if-a-row-exists-using-linq-to-sql/48869497#48869497

Comment: @BradleyUffner I tried the ICollection, IQueyiable, in fact those extensions are still sat there. I still have the same problem.

Comment: @Tod That is interesting, but I wonder if the `LIKE` is influencing the result - my tests of `Count` versus `Any` for `==` tests on a related table or a straight table, `Any` is always faster. Consider [this article](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andrew_kelly/archive/2007/12/15/exists-vs-count-the-battle-never-ends.aspx).

Comment: Why do you think `Count` is faster than `Any` for the queries you are doing?

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your specific question, but I suggest you rethink how you're approaching the query.

Let's use some descriptive names that make it easier to understand: do any households have a resident with the first name of "Bobby"?

```
// your way
Ctx.Households.Count( hh => hh.Residents.Count( r => r.FirstName == "Bobby" ) > 0 ) > 0
```

Yuck, it's backwards.  Start with residents:

```
Ctx.Residents.Count( r => 
    r.FirstName == "Bobby"
    && r.Household != null ) // if needed
    > 0;
```

Now, will that generate SQL significantly different than the below?

```
Ctx.Residents.Any( r => r.FirstName == "Bobby" && r.Household != null)
```

edit:

Here's a true MCVE that results in the opposite of your conclusion:

```
/*
create table TestDatum
(
    TestValue nchar(36) not null
)
*/

/*
set nocount on
declare @count int
declare @start datetime
declare @end datetime
set @count = 0

set @start = GETDATE()

while @count < 14000000
begin
    insert TestDatum values( CONVERT(nchar(36), NEWID()) )

    set @count = @count + 1

    if (@count % 100000) = 0
    begin
        print convert(nvarchar, @count)
    end
end

set @end = GETDATE()

select CONVERT(nvarchar, DATEDIFF(ms, @start, @end))
*/

/*
-- "Any" test
declare @startdt datetime, @enddt datetime
set @startdt = GETDATE()
DECLARE @p0 NVarChar(1000) = '%abcdef%'

SELECT 
    (CASE 
        WHEN EXISTS(
            SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
            FROM TestDatum AS [t0]
            WHERE [t0].TestValue LIKE @p0
            ) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
     END) AS [value]
set @enddt = GETDATE()
select DATEDIFF(ms, @startdt, @enddt) -- ~7000ms
*/
/*
-- "Count" test
declare @startdt datetime, @enddt datetime
set @startdt = GETDATE()
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 NVarChar(1000) = '%abcdef%'
-- EndRegion
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [value]
FROM TestDatum AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].TestValue LIKE @p0
set @enddt = GETDATE()
select DATEDIFF(ms, @startdt, @enddt) -- > 48000ms
*/
```

Comment: Yes SQL Translates any to: CASE 
        WHEN EXISTS(
            SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
            FROM. Count is just COUNT

Comment: @Tod - ok, and you're saying counting all records is somehow faster or more optimal than short circuiting upon finding the first record?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm saying. I don't know why, I've posted on SO before, check the comments from the question for the link. Some data can be comparable in terms of the speed of the two methods. Other times it can be much much quicker to Count.

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) reproducing this behavior?

Comment: Like I said, link in the comments for the question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648795/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-determine-if-a-row-exists-using-linq-to-sql/48869497#48869497

Comment: My results from the above edit demonstrated the complete opposite conclusion (as described in my comment on your post) - ~7000ms for the `any` method and over 48000ms for the `count` method.